# Calling Terraform from Ansible

Tags: azure, ansible, terraform

When i am using terraform modules directly being called from shell scripts it works fine.

But when i am wrapping same shell script which is called from an ansible task it fails. validated all the environment variables for ARM credentials which are being passed. All are fine, but somehow not getting any success to run terraform as an ansible task.

Below is the error I get

> Error refreshing state: 1 error(s) occurred:\n\n* module.oracle_server.provider.azurerm: Unable to list provider registration status, it is possible that this is due to invalid credentials or the service principal does not have permission to use the Resource Manager API, Azure error: azure.BearerAuthorizer#WithAuthorization: Failed to refresh the Token for request to https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/****/providers?api-version=2016-02-01: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: adal:

#### UPDATEd by the editor

Please update your ansible codes here, more than in comment, lost all format.

```
- name: Terraform Module 
  terraform: 
    project_path: "{{ terraform_module_path }}" 
    state: "{{ item.infra_state }}" 
    variables: 
      platform: "{{ platform }}" 
      application_name: "{{ application_name }}" 
      environment: "{{ env }}"
```

Comment: Tried in terraform module of ansible as well, below is the code snippet when calling terraform module of ansible- name: Terraform Module
  terraform: 
    project_path: "{{ terraform_module_path }}"
    state: "{{ item.infra_state }}"
    variables: 
      platform: "{{ platform }}"
      application_name: "{{ application_name }}"
      environment: "{{ env }}"

Comment: you're getting a lot of downvotes, i think most people would use ansible in terraform not the otherway around. I've seen it done your way, but only really badly.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it can't properly set the azure credentials, so please check if you include the provider codes or not.

```
# Configure the Azure Provider
provider "azurerm" {
  # whilst the `version` attribute is optional, we recommend pinning to a given version of the Provider
  version = "=1.21.0"
}
```

Reference: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/